# HardhatError: Artifact for contract "CertData.sol" not found

Tags: solidity, hardhat, polygon, hardhat-deploy

I am trying to create an ABI  from my Solidity smart contract.

When I run `npx hardhat run --network testnet scripts/deploy.js` It gives me and HardhatError: Artifact for contract "CertData" not found.

I am pretty sure that I did not do any spelling mistakega in the smart contract name.

My deploy.js script is located in scripts/deploy.js

Content of script:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const CertData = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("CertData");
  const certData = await CertData.deploy();
  await certData.deployed();

  const txHash = certData.deployTransaction.hash;
  const txReceipt = await hre.ethers.provider.waitForTransaction(txHash);
  console.log(
    `check your contract: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/${txReceipt.contractAddress}`
  );
  console.log("contract address:", txReceipt.contractAddress);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

And my CertData.sol file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract CertData {
  Cert[] private certs;
  mapping(address => Cert[]) private authorToCerts;

  struct Cert {
    string title;
    string description;
    string owner;
  }

  function store(string memory title, string memory description, string memory owner) public {
    Cert memory cert = Cert(title, description, owner);

    certs.push(cert);
    authorToCerts[msg.sender].push(cert);
  }

  function retrieveAllCerts() public view returns (Cert[] memory) {
    return certs;
  }

  function retrieveCertsByAuthor() public view returns (Cert[] memory) {
    return authorToCerts[msg.sender];
  }
}
```

hardhat.config.js file content:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("dotenv").config();

const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337,
    },
    testnet: {
      url: "https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com",
      accounts: [privateKey],
    },
    mainnet: {
      url: "https://polygon-rpc.com",
      accounts: [privateKey],
    },
  },
  solidity: "0.8.4",
};
```

My folder structure:

[image]

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename the folder `/contract` to `/contracts`, as hardhat `path.sources` defaults to `/contracts`.
Or specify otherwise in `paths` in your `hardhat.config.js` the following:

```
  paths: {
    sources: "./contract",
  },
```

See full list of properties for `paths` in the docs:

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config#path-configuration

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem!